# Using *args to pass dataframe to function

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I would like to write a function where several dataframes can be passed as *args in order to draw some plots. That is something like:

```
def f_plot (*args):
    p = None
    if args == df1:
        ...plot rules for df1...
        p = plot.show()
    elif args == df2:
        ...plot rules for df2...
        p = plot.show()
    else:
        raise ValueError("No *args were passed!!!)
    return p
```

By the way, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty(), a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

These are simplified df examples:

```
df1 = {'home': [A,B,C,D,E], 'away': [F,G,H,I,J], 'score_in': [2,1,3,2,0], 'score_out': [1,3,1,0,2], ‘competition’: [highschool, university, highschool, university, MLS, university]}

df2=df1.groupby('competition').get_group('university')
```

I would like to create, for this example, if arg is equal to df1, n subplots in the same fig regarding scores where n are the competitions, while, if arg is equal to one of the possible df2, a single plot different from the previuos.

Any help?

Comment: Please post the entire stack frame so we know which line had the error. We shouldn't have to guess.

Comment: ...but guessing anyway, in `if args == df1`, `args` is a tuple. I have no idea what `df1` is, a dataframe presumably? First, it isn't a tuple and `pandas` gets angry when you try to make a dataframe either true or false. As it says, its ambiguous. Perhaps `a.empty(), a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`. That's a good suggestion!

Comment: I don't get a.empty(), a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(): have I any manner to set an if condition within my function avoiding True or False? Of course, df1 and so on are dataframes as I wrote on top.

Comment: Of course, you said that the args were dataframes and didn't mention what df1 and df2 were. In your code `df1` could easily be a tuple of dataframes, as  in "dataframe collection 1". Since args is a tuple it would be reasonable to compare it against another tuple and to put multiple dataframes on a single plot.

Comment: A dataframe can have multiple values and multiple ways to decide truthfulness. Is it true because its not empty, at least one value in the df is true, all values in the df are true? That's why you have to specify.

Comment: Is the intent of this function to make multiple plots from multiple arguements in a loop? Then you'd do `for plot_df in args:` and in that code suite the check would be `if plot_df.equals(df1):`.

Comment: Thank you tdelaney, now I got. df1 is a simple dataframe and df2 can be a groupby.get_group subset. The intent is to make two different kinds of plots, separately, if the parameter I pass is df1, some histograms subplots with their rules; if it is df2, a single plot for each df2 subset type which have to be passed

Comment: I'm still a bit confused over requirements. If you want to pass a single dataframe of a get_group subset, you likely don't need multiple arguements at all. Just `def f_plot(plot_df)` - that is, the single df or group to be plotted. If you want either 1 df for the df1 check or a bunch of params for the df2 check, then your first if would be `if len(args) == 1 and args[0].equals(df1):`

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I’ll try your syntax soon, I update you. Meanwhile, I edited The questione in order to try to clarify the issue. Thank you for your time

Comment: Yes tdelaney, I agree with something like ```def f_plot(plot_df)```, but my intent is to associate a kind of plot for each df passed as argument, but I cannot succed into it. For instance, ```if plot_df argument is df1```, f_plot will return an histogram, while ```if plot_df is df2 f_plot``` will return a piechart. I tried with ```if len(args)==1 and args[0].equals(df)``` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`*args` is used as a a tuple so from your code here it doesn't necessarily look like it's required to use it.

That aside though, you can use the .equals() function for pandas DataFrame:
https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/dataframe/dataframe-equals.php

I'm not sure what is contained in df1 or df2 though

Comment: Thank you Uy Tran. df1 and df2 are two dataframes with 6 columns whose two are numerics and I would like to create a function with a generic parameter to pass which can be equal to df1 or df2 in order to make one kind of plot or an other one. I thought to do this with an if condition and *args parameter, but there are troubles for true/false matching with df I suppose.. could .equals() help for my goal?

Comment: `*args` is used when you want to pass in some undefined amount of parameters. It would allow you to pass in multiple DataFrames within a single call of the function. It appears that you only plot one dataframe at a time so you wouldn't need to use `*args`

Comment: .equals() returns whether or not the two dataframes have the same contents. If you could clarify how you want to compare your input dataFrame to df1 or df2.

Comment: Actually, I don’t want to compare nothing. I just need to let my function knows if dataframe I pass as argument is of “type 1” or “type 2”. If it is 1 I have some rule for plotting, else I have others.

Comment: Originally, I did something like f_plot(df1==None, df2==None): if df1 !=None and df2==None ..rules to plot 1.. elif: df1==None and df2!=None ..files to plot 2.  But it doesn’t work